# 8 x 12 wooden bridge over creek

Tags: structural-engineering

I am installing wooden bridge over small creek for ATV and tractor size is 8 x 12. I'm using 6 x 6 post, total of 9 posts. 3 posts will be in center of creek. In summer time its usually fairly low or no water. My questions are after holes dug should I put gravel in hole then post then concrete also pertaining to the 3 post in creek?

I am not sure how low water table is. Should we use gravel in these holes also if we run into water after holes are dug?

Thank you.